# Redirect URLs with query string by RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect /video/{x1}?width={x2}&height={x3} to /proxy/file/{xf}{x1}?{x1}?width={x2]&height={x3}
And I want {xf} to be anything
For example: `https://another.domain/`
and {x1} to support folder and file paths together:
/somedir/somefile.png

So a complete example of what I want:

```
https://example.com/video/somedir/somefile.png?width=123&height=321 to https://example.com/proxy/file/somedir/somefile.png?https://another.domain/somedir/somefile.png?width=123&height=321
```

This is the code I tested but it didn't work :

```
# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?width=([0-9]*)&height=([0-9]*)
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /proxy/file/$1?https://somedomain/$1$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: That final rewriting target you suggest is invalid. You'd have to encode characters like ":" and "/" in there. Without encoding this _might_ work in some situations, but it might also break from one day to the other, since there is no guarantee that such invalid requests will get handled in a predictable way.

Comment: Also you write that you try to redirect URLs, yet your implementation attempt shows no redirection, but an internal rewrite. So what is it you actually want?

Comment: And you forgot to tell us what "didn't work" actually means. What happens when those rules are in place and you make a test request? You get an error? Which error? You get an unexpected result? What result? Your logic crashes? What does your error log file say? The universe implodes? How does that look?

Comment: 1- Changing the route is not done at will.
2- I want to do internal rewriting

Comment: I tested this "RewriteRule ^(.*) /v1/proxy/file/$1?https: //example.com/uploads/$1 [NC,L] " and it works correctly
But it cannot redirect query strings

Comment: Well, then add the `QSA` flag. It is documented. "Query String Append".